# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener fires when the user enters in the preference activity the first time

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I've a PreferenceActivity and a Service in my application among other components.

When a preference is changed, I want my service to do some work depending on the preference changes, so I configured my service as a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

My problem is when the user enters in the preference activity the first time. The `OnSharedPreferenceChange` event is fired once per preference in the "preferences.xml", although no preference has been changed.

How could I avoid this behaviour? I don't want the `OnSharedPreferenceChange` event is fired the first time the user enters in the "preferences activity".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a flag in sharedpreferences, just like that

```
 if( prefs.getBoolean( "preferenceFirstTime", true ) ) {
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("preferenceFirstTime", false);
      editor.commit();
 } else {
      //this is not the first time 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have given me the idea to solve the problem. What I've done is to create a flag as you told me. In the 'onSharedPreferenceChanged' method, I just only check this flag. If it is the first time, I don't do anything. And in the "onResume" method of the PreferenceActivity, I put the flag to 'false', so next calls to 'onSharedPreferenceChanged' method will do what it is expected. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: The aswer is wrong, but the comment is right: you have to set flag in PreferenceActivity.onResume, not in onSharedPreferenceChanged.

Comment: This answer is wrong and the comment isn't promoting a good approach either. One should setup preference defaults in `MainActivity.onCreate()` as shown in @kakopappa 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i found another way to fix this problem using this.

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```

This way you can set the default values for preferences before register for changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 or more PreferenceScreen you need to use:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, true);
```

for each PreferenceScreen. But on the last one use:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```

Example: You have three PreferenceScreen, do this:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference1, true);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference2, true);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference3, false);
```